# Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role error when using Google Cloud Vision API - PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: postman, google-cloud-vision

I am following this article https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels.
I am using POSTMAN to send the request and gcloud shell cli (cloud based shell not local). I have set it up accordingly by referring to that article and I am getting this issue right now. Caller does not have required permission to use project ***. Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission and then retry.

I have set the user role via the console already but I'm still getting this error.
Is it required to install gcloud cli on local if I am using the cloud shell.

[image: role table]